# SQL JOIN or UNION on same id

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi how to get from two tables

```
 | id | name  |
 |----|-------|
 | 1  | John  |
 | 1  | Bruce |
 | 1  | Tom   |
```

and

```
 | id | goal  |
 |----|-------|
 | 1  | 11    |
 | 1  | 22    |
```

get select with a result like

```
 | id | name |goal  |
 |----|------|------|
 | 1  |John  | 11   |
 | 1  |Bruce | 22   |
 | 1  |Tom   |      |
```

I tried joins and union but i didnt get any result, please help! Using oracle pl/sql.

Comment: Please share the queries you tried.

Comment: Can you explain the logic you need to implement? Are you sure your ids are correct? Why will John have 11 as goal, while Bruce ( same id) has 22 and Tom has no goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.  You don't have a join key for generating the values.  In fact, there is really no way to "align" the values this way, because SQL tables are inherently unordered.

One thing you can do is generate a row number and use this for the `join`.  One method is:

```
select id, max(name) as name, max(goal) as goal
from ((select id, name, NULL as goal, rownum as rn
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select id, NULL, goal, rownum as rn
       from t2
      )
     ) t12
group by id, rn;
```

Note:  the orders in the two columns are arbitrary relative to each other, unless you have a column specifying the ordering.